# Nested classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, initialization, nested

I can't figure out how to initialize a class from a parent class variable. I'm trying to accomplish this:

```
x = A::B.new('my string')
myObject = x::C.new(**params)
```

and the program I'm calling is organized similar to:

```
module A
   ...<stuff>...
   class B
       ...<stuff>....
       class C < B
           ...<stuff>...
       end
   end
end
```

I want to initialize the class `C` after initializing the parent class `B`. That way, I can have access to class `B`'s variables and methods from class `C`.

When I try to execute my program, I get:

```
"#<A::B:0x...............>" is not a class/module (TypeError)
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for initializing nested classes like this?

Comment: It seems you expect this to work like Beta or Newspeak nested classes, but Ruby doesn't have nested classes. These are simply namespaced constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't construct an instance from an instance - the whole module hierarchy is only applicable to modules and classes. Since `x` is neither, the parser has no idea what `::` is supposed to do.

The idea behind nested classes is that they are namespaced within the parent class, no more, no less. In effect, `class B` acts like a module prefix to `class C`, but there's no inherent relationship between them (by being nested alone; you *do* inherit `C` from `B` in your example, which is what gives you the relationship), and certainly not between an *instance* of `B` and the class `C`

Instead, I would recommend constructing a C directly with 'my string', then calling `#super` in the initialize method, like so:

```
myObject = A::B::C.new('my string', **params)
```

and in the implementation:

```
module A
  class B
    def initialize(some_string)
      @some_string = some_string
    end
    class C < B
      def initialize(str, params)
        super(str)
        ...
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, the namespace operator `::` can only be applied to a class/module. If `x` were the class `A::B`, then `x::C` should work. It does not make sense to apply `::C` on an instance of `A::B`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `::` to `x`'s class, not `x` itself. So you just need a call to the [`class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-class) method:

```
x = A::B.new('my string')
myObject = x.class::C.new(**params)
```

For example, this sort of thing:

```
module A
  class B
    class C
    end
  end
end

pancakes = A::B.new
eggs     = pancakes.class::C.new

puts pancakes.inspect
puts eggs.inspect
```

gives you something like this:

```
#<A::B:0x007faea90b6a58>
#<A::B::C:0x007faea90b6a30>
```